# Adding another element to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which looks like this,

```
{'023': {'ARTERIAL': {'Age': '043Y'},
  'PORTAL': {'Age': '043Y'},
  'VENOUS': {'Age': '043Y'}},
 '024': {'ARTERIAL': {'Age': '048Y'},
  'PORTAL': {'Age': '048Y'},
  'VENOUS': {'Age': '048Y'}}}
```

I have set this up using this ,

```
data_dict={}
for folders in os.listdir(new_path):
    for AVP in os.listdir(os.path.join(new_path, folders)):
        for files in os.listdir(os.path.join(new_path, folders, AVP)):          
            file = dicom.read_file(os.path.join(new_path, folders, AVP, files))
            Name = file.Name
            Age = file.Age
            at = file.AcquisitionNumber
            data_dict.setdefault(folders, {}).setdefault(AVP,{}).setdefault('Age',file.Age)
            break
```

Now along with Age i would like to add more key value items to the age dictionary ,Something like this

```
{'023': {'ARTERIAL': {'Age': '043Y','number': 43, 'time':12:00},
  'PORTAL': {'Age': '043Y','number': 3, 'time':2:00},
  'VENOUS': {'Age': '043Y','number': 93, 'time':1:00}},
```

i have tried

```
data_dict.setdefault(folders, {}).setdefault(AVP,{}).setdefault('Age',file.Age).setdefault(file.AcquisitionNumber, file.AcquisitionNumber)
```

which gives me

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Any suggestions on how i can add more key value pairs will be helpful,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setdefault` returns the value of the dictionary element, either the one that was already there or the default you provided. The first two `setdefault()` calls return the nested dictionaries, but the last one returns `file.Age`, which is a string.

Assign the last dictionary to a variable and then set the values you want in it:

```
d = data_dict.setdefault(folders, {}).setdefault(AVP,{})
d['Age'] = file.Age
d['number'] = file.AcquisitionNumber
```

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: Works Like a charm,Thank you so much

Comment: @DecentMakeover It is generally good etiquette to accept the answer that worked best for you (click the checkmark on the left).